# Xcode the image in image.xcassets always show Unassigned

Tags: ios, xcode, assets

The image in local Xcode works all good, like below:
[image]

But when push the code into remote server and build Jenkins job, the image always show `Unassigned` with yellow warning icon like below:

[image]

The issued can be solved locally by click `Universal` on right panel. But the Jenkins pull code every time the job starts, so it's not a workaround.

Seems the `Universal` option isn't under git control. Not sure why this the `Universal` checked locally, but Jenkins workspace the option unchecked? I have tried removed/renamed the wrong icons.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the `Contents.json` for the image asset are missed/ignored.